# Cannot read strings from form

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am writing form that lets user to change his password. Instead of passing `User` object to `form`, I am passing 3 empty Strings. Everything is okay, but when I am passing `Submit`, Strings returns as empty. Is there any way to get String from forms in Spring without packaging them into objects like `changePasswordForm` with 3 String fields?

**My code:**

**Change password view:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div th:replace="/fragments/header"> </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Changing password</h1>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/user/changePassword/} + ${user.id}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Current password</label>
                    <input type="password" th:field="${currentPassword}" class="form-control" placeholder="Your current password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>New password</label>
                    <input type="password" th:field="${newPassword}" class="form-control" placeholder="Your new password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>New password confirmation</label>
                    <input type="password" th:field="${newPasswordConfirmation}" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your new password"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div th:replace="/fragments/footer"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**User controller:**

```
package io.gromo13.personalBlog.controller;

import io.gromo13.personalBlog.service.RoleService;
import io.gromo13.personalBlog.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import io.gromo13.personalBlog.model.User;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller

@RequestMapping("/user")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
RoleService roleService;

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

public void setRoleService(RoleService roleService) {
    this.roleService = roleService;
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String profile(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    User user = userService.get(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "/user/profile";
}

@GetMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.getAll());
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "/user/register";
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerSubmit(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "/user/register";
    userService.add(user);

    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}

@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String edit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    User user = userService.get(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("password", "");

    return "/user/edit";
}

@PostMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "/user/edit";
    userService.edit(user);

    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}

@GetMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
public String changePasword(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("currentPassword", "");
    model.addAttribute("newPassword", "");
    model.addAttribute("newPasswordConfirmation", "");

    return "/user/changePassword";
}

@PostMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
public String changePasswordSubmit(@PathVariable Long id,
                                   @ModelAttribute("currentPassword") String currentPassword,
                                   @ModelAttribute("newPassword") String newPassword,
                                   @ModelAttribute("newPasswordConfirmation") String newPasswordConfirmation,
                                   BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "/user/changePassword";

    User user = userService.get(id);
    if (newPassword.equals(newPasswordConfirmation) && user.getPassword().equals(currentPassword)) {
        user.setPassword(newPassword);
        userService.edit(user);
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}

@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    userService.delete(id);

    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}
```

}

Actually my whole page is working fine, I just cannot read single Strings passed to forms without wrapping to objects.

Every tutorial about forms in Spring I found is passing object like `xForm` or `User` to view and read them. It works for me too, but I do not see sense in creating special object just for single form.

Comment: You can just take the strings as `request.getParameter("paramName")` and in controller method add argument `HttpServletRequest request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `th:field` to `name` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div th:replace="/fragments/header"> </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Changing password</h1>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/user/changePassword/} + ${user.id}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Current password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="currentPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Your current password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>New password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="newPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Your new password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>New password confirmation</label>
                    <input type="password" name="newPasswordConfirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your new password"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div th:replace="/fragments/footer"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

remove this from controller

```
@GetMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
public String changePasword(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("currentPassword", ""); //remove
    model.addAttribute("newPassword", ""); //remove
    model.addAttribute("newPasswordConfirmation", ""); //remove

    return "/user/changePassword";
}
```

and here change ModelAttribute to RequestParam Annotation

```
@PostMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
public String changePasswordSubmit(@PathVariable Long id,
                                   @RequestParam("currentPassword") String currentPassword,
                                   @RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword,
                                   @RequestParam("newPasswordConfirmation") String newPasswordConfirmation) {
```

this sentence bindingResult not work because this validate a POJO using validations annotations

```
//if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
//    return "/user/changePassword";
```

for this case the best way is create a new POJO with those fields and then validate them.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I have to add POJO just for validation. It's the only way to do this. Could you explain, why th:object wasn't working? Is it using setters and getters for setting values and that's why it wasn't able to set Strings values?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: check the new answer

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the validation you need to create a POJO and add the constraints.

**1)**

```
public class ChangePass {

    @Size(min = 8,max = 13, message = "error current password between {min} to {max}")
    private String currentPassword;

    @Size(min = 8,max = 13,message = "error new password between {min} to {max}")
    private String newPassword;

    //validate later
    private String newPasswordConfirmation;
}
```

**2)**

then you need to add a instance of this POJO in the view.

```
 @GetMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
    public String changePasword(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userPass", new ChangePass()); // adding model

        return "/user/changePassword";
    }
```

**3)**

in your form you need to fix 2 things add

`th:object="${userPass}"` and  add `th:field="*{currentPassword}"` not `th:field="${currenctPassword}"` the difference is **" * "**

```
<form th:action="@{/user/changePassword/} + ${user.id}" method="post" th:object="${userPass}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Current password</label>
                <input type="password" th:field="*{currentPassword}" class="form-control" placeholder="Your current password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>New password</label>
                <input type="password" th:field="*{newPassword}" class="form-control" placeholder="Your new password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>New password confirmation</label>
                <input type="password" th:field="*{newPasswordConfirmation}" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your new password"/>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
        </form>
```

**4)**

and the Post Method should be...

```
@PostMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
    public String changePassword(@PathVariable Long id,
                                 @ModelAttribute("userPass"), 
                                 @Valid ChangePass change,
                                 BindingResult errors){

        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "/user/changePassword";
        }

        //your next code
```